sequence (unknown member) : invalid request
in PowerPoint vba we have a code that have this error:

sequence (unknown member) : invalid request

if I delete this part of the code (Level:=msoAnimateChartBySeries) then its works!!!
but I need this & I don't want to delete it. so please help me ...
thanks
Dim PPApp As Object
Dim ppshape As Shape
Dim oEffect As Effect

new_sld_count = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

For Each ppshape In ActivePresentation.Slides(new_sld_count).Shapes
                                                     
If ppshape.Type = msoChart Then
               Set oEffect= ActivePresentation.Slides(new_sld_count).TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=ppshape, _
                                                     effectId:=msoAnimEffectFade,Level:=msoAnimateChartBySeries)
      
end if                                               
                                                 
Next ppshape


Maybe the chart object cannot accept Level parameter.

we can set level for chart by PowerPoint It self, so i think we can do it in vba, but i don't know How!!!!
